# Sentiment analysis - arousal

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I am really a beginner in programming, and I have run into a problem. I am making a comparative analysis between fake news and real news. I have a text corpus with aprox. 3000 real news and 3000 fake news. I need to figure out whether fake or real news evoke more high-arousal emotions. I want to do that by using Warriner et. al. word list: http://crr.ugent.be/archives/1003

I have imported the word list to my script:

```
warriner = pd.read_csv('warriner.csv', sep = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
print warriner.head()
```

I (think, I) want to find the Arousal Mean Sum, which in the word list is called `A.Mean.Sum`. But I can't make it work, `Spyder` just say: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'.
Can anyone help? I have already calculated the sentiment scores by using `LabMT` as seen below, but I can't make Warringer et al work.

```
text_scored = [] for text in df['text']: sent_score = tm.labMT_sent(text) 
text_scored.append(sent_score)
df['abs_sent'] = text_scored #adding the scored text to the df
```

relative sentiment score

```
text_scored = [] for text in df['text']: sent_score = tm.labMT_sent(text, rel = True)
text_scored.append(sent_score)
df['rel_sent'] = text_scored #adding the scored text to the df
overall mean

df['abs_sent'].mean() df['abs_sent'].loc[df['label'] == 'FAKE'].mean()    
#'fake' mean = - 22,1 df['abs_sent'].loc[df['label'] == 'REAL'].mean() 
#'real' mean = - 41,95
```

relative score mean calculations

```
df['rel_sent'].mean() #overall mean df['rel_sent'].loc[df['label'] == 'FAKE'].mean() 
#'fake' mean = - 0,02 df['rel_sent'].loc[df['label'] == 'REAL'].mean() 
#'real' mean = - 0,05
```

Answer (score 2):

The example code you provided is hard for me to read. You're reporting the problem as having to do with A.Mean.Sum, but there's no code relating to that. There are also references to Spyder and DataFrame without explanation, code, or tags. Finally, the title should tell the potential answerer something about the problem itself, not the general field the code is working with. The current one expects the reader to find what they're supposed to do from within the report.

I'll readily admit I'm a novice here, but I suggest reading the intro [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and clarifying your question with it.

I'm also guessing this is a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) related question, so its docs page might help you.

I hope I was of any help!